# Php file upload

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

**Php code**

```
$target = "upload/";
$nameF = "";

$targetImage = "upload/";
$nameI = "";

if (!empty($_FILES['fileUP']['name'])) {
  print_r("ce il file");
  $target = $target . basename($_FILES['fileUP']['name']);
  $nameF = $_FILES['fileUP']['name'];
  if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileUP']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
    echo -1;
  }
}

if (!empty($_FILES['imageUP']['name'])) {
  $targetImage = $targetImage . basename($_FILES['imageUP']['name']);
  $nameI = $_FILES['imageUP']['name'];
  if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imageUP']['tmp_name'], $targetImage)) {
    echo -1;
  }
}

$title = $_POST['title'];
$admin = $_POST['admin'];
$content = $_POST['content'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO  news (title,admin,content,img,file) values('$title','$admin','$content','$nameI','$nameF')";
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

if ($result === TRUE) {

  echo 1;
} else {
  echo -1;
}
```

**Form**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="insert" class="bs-example bs-example-form" method="POST">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Titolo</span>
        <input id="title" name="title" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Titolo">
    </div>

    <br>

    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Admin</span>
        <input id="admin" name="admin" type="text" class="form-control" value='{{$utente|lower}}'
               placeholder='{{$utente}}'>
    </div>

    <br><br> <br> <br>

    <div class="input-group">

        <span class="input-group-addon">Immagine</span>
        <input id="image" name="imageUP" accept="image/*" type="file" class="form-control"
               placeholder="Immagine">

    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">File</span>
        <input id="image" name="fileUP" id="fileToUpload" type="file" class="form-control"
               placeholder="FIle">
    </div>

    <br>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-font"></span></span>
        <input id="content" name="content" type="text" class="form-control"
               placeholder="Contenuto">
    </div>
    <br>
    <button id="crea" type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Crea</button>
</form>
```

**Ajax request**

```
$('#insert').submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = new FormData($(this)[0]);

  $.ajax
  ({
    url: 'uploads.php',
     data: data,
     type: 'post',
     processData: false,
     contentType: false,
     success: function (response) {
    response = parseInt(response);
    switch (response) {
    case -1: //errore generico
    alert("errore");
    break;
    case 1:
    alert("la creazione della news è andata a buon fine");
    break;
    }

  close ajax call..
```

**My problem is:**
the script work but not well, i've notice that query don't insert data if i put text in the 'content' input and upload image.

In the console I've this **error**:

> not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/fakepath/xx.jpg

when i work in localhost i haven't this error and query ALWAYS insert data. Now i've problem and i am in real server.

Anyone know to fix it?ù
I need your help

Comment: I just tried it and it worked , I tried again and it did not work. IT's so strange!

Comment: when the script didn't work, in the console i see this request has no preview available, and no -1

Comment: Is *upload* folder having read & write permissions?

Comment: yes , i can upload image with no data(no text in input)

Comment: if i have text in input the script work 2 times out of 7

Comment: I got it. Wait for my answer.

Comment: i hope is the final answer :)

Comment: @NanaPartykar the code work, i've notice  chrome automatic compilation gives me problems and does not insert, is the only case. Thank you so much, you've been a great help !!

Comment: And So is the answer *reverted back* @Francesco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. And, let me know. Use whole code as it is. I will explain in few minutes. First try.

```
$target = "upload/";
$nameF = "";

$targetImage = "upload/";
$nameI = "";

$flag = 1;

if (!empty( $_FILES['fileUP']['name'])) {
    print_r("ce il file");
    $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['fileUP']['name']);
    $nameF =$_FILES['fileUP']['name'];
    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileUP']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
      $flag = -1;
    }
}

if (!empty( $_FILES['imageUP']['name'])) {
    $targetImage = $targetImage . basename( $_FILES['imageUP']['name']);
    $nameI =$_FILES['imageUP']['name'];
    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imageUP']['tmp_name'], $targetImage)) {
      $flag = -1;
    }
}

$title = $_POST['title'];
$admin = $_POST['admin'];
$content = $_POST['content'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO  news (title,admin,content,img,file) values('$title','$admin','$content','$nameI','$nameF')";
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

if ($result === TRUE) {
  $flag = 1;
}
else {
  $flag = -1;
}

if($flag == -1){
  echo -1;
} else {
  echo 1;
}
```